# Is a Wild Card a match to a Wild Draw Color Card in Uno Flip

Tags: uno-flip

When the **"Wild Draw Color Card"** is played, the next player must start drawing cards.
If they draw a **"Wild Card"**, does it qualify as the selected Color?

Answer (score 2):

No. A Wild Card has no color. It can be played on any card regardless of color, number, or symbol, but it doesn't have a color itself.

From [the rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/GDR44-English.pdf):

> you must match a card from your hand to the
>   card on the top of the DISCARD pile, either by number, color or symbol [...] Alternatively, the player can put down a Wild card (See FUNCTIONS OF ACTION CARDS).

The "Draw Color" card specifies that the target draw cards until they draw one whose color is the named color.